# Magento 2 subscription success email not sent

Tags: magento2, email, newsletter

after I subscribed for newsletter, indeed there is a thank you message alert in front-end as well as new subscriber lists that we can see in back-end. however there is no success email sent to the mail.

I tried several things to do, like :

- activate cron job
- checking spam
- looking into odd thing in this file `vendor\magento\module-newsletter\Model\Subscriber.php`
- even, changing email template (create custom template)

but no luck, still no email after subscribing.

FYI I'm using magento 2.2.9 upgraded from 2.1.7, even in version 2.1.7 the subscription success email is not sending.

may there some possible issue ?

Comment: Did you installed any SMTP extension?

Comment: @RohanHapani I did not install any smtp extension :|